# how to configure stripe using apple pay & google pay integration

Tags: node.js, angular7, applepay, google-pay

currently my website configure with stripe CC also I need to setup stripe with apple pay & google pay i don't know how to configure the payment button integration.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of approaches to integrating Apple Pay and Google Pay via Stripe:

- The [Payment Request Button](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button), or
- Directly with Apple Pay and Google Pay

The first option is generally going to be an easier integration, however, the reason you might choose the second option (for Google Pay) is, cross browser support, Google Pay button branding, and localization support.

If choosing the [Payment Request Button](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button), then the [prerequisites section](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#prerequisites) should have the information required.

- Apple Pay: the most notable task is [verifying your domain](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#verifying-your-domain-with-apple-pay)
- Google Pay: should work out of the box via the Payment Request Button

If looking at direct integration with their respective buttons/APIs, refer to their resources:

- Apple Pay:

  - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web ([example](https://applepaydemo.apple.com/))
  - https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay#web
- Google Pay:

  - https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/overview
  - https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay#web

Note that [Stripe's Checkout API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) will automatically include support for Apple Pay.

I found the following article helpful to understand the differences between Payment Request API (which is what the Payment Request Button is based on) and Google Pay: https://medium.com/dev-channel/web-payments-payment-request-api-and-google-pay-a1073e405235